# How do I more reliably get a variable from a dynamically changing element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-masonry, scrolltop

I'm still a novice with coding, and thus have come to a standstill with this bug I can't seem to fix. I'm working on my personal website http://yeemachine.com that has a sticky navbar that changes its "html content" when a certain threshold in the scrolltop function has been reached.

This is what I'm using to load the initial function. The bug comes when it tries to load var=pdr or the height of .class2. .class2 is a div that houses images set using Masonry.js. It's a hit or miss sometimes. Most of the time on first load, it gives height the div as 2000+ px which would be the height if all the images are stacked on top of each other.

```
    $(window).load(function() {

        var  mn = $(".main-nav");
    var  mns = "main-nav-scrolled";
    var  hdr = $('#container').height();
    var pdr = $('.class2').height();
    var gdr = $('.class1').height();
    var sdr = $('.hundred').height();

    console.log(gdr);
    console.log(pdr);

        var windowPosY = $(this).scrollTop();

        $(window).scroll(function() {

        if($(this).scrollTop() > (hdr*.85) && windowPosY < (hdr+(gdr)))
        {
            mn.addClass(mns);
         $( ".iconcontainer li a" ).html( "<i class='fa fa-chevron-up'></i><br>Design<br><i class='fa fa-chevron-down'></i>" );
         $( ".iconcontainer li a" ).css( "font-size", "10px" );

        }
        if($(this).scrollTop() < (hdr*.85) && windowPosY ){
            mn.removeClass(mns);
             $( ".iconcontainer li a" ).html( "<i class='fa fa-chevron-up hideicon'></i><br>Richard<br>Yee<br><i class='fa fa-chevron-down'></i>" );
             $( ".iconcontainer li a" ).css( "font-size", "10px" );

        }
            if($(this).scrollTop() > (hdr+gdr) && windowPosY < (hdr+gdr+pdr)){
                $( ".iconcontainer li a" ).html( "<i class='fa fa-chevron-up'></i><br>Painting?<br><i class='fa fa-chevron-down'></i>" );
                $( ".iconcontainer li a" ).css( "font-size", "10px" );

            }
            if($(this).scrollTop() > (hdr+gdr+pdr) && windowPosY < (hdr+gdr+pdr+sdr)){
                $( ".iconcontainer li a" ).html( "<i class='fa fa-chevron-up'></i><br>Sound<br><i class='fa fa-chevron-down hideicon'></i>" );
                $( ".iconcontainer li a" ).css( "font-size", "10px" );

            }
        });
```

I do have, along with this initial load function a resizing function that fixes the problem everytime the window is resized.

```
    var resizeTimeout;

      $(window).resize(function() {
        clearTimeout(resizeTimeout);
        resizeTimeout= setTimeout(doneResizing, 500);
     });

      doneResizing(); //trigger resize handling code for initialization
 });


function doneResizing()
{

        mn = $(".main-nav");
        mns = "main-nav-scrolled";
        hdr = $('#container').height();
        gdr = $('.class1').height();
        pdr = $('.class2').height();
        sdr = $('.hundred').height();



        $(window).scroll(function() {
            var windowPosY = $(this).scrollTop();
            console.log(gdr);
            if($(this).scrollTop() > (hdr*.85) && windowPosY < (hdr+(gdr)))
            {
                mn.addClass(mns);
             $( ".iconcontainer li a" ).html( "<i class='fa fa-chevron-up'></i><br>Design<br><i class='fa fa-chevron-down'>" );
             $( ".iconcontainer li a" ).css( "font-size", "10px" );

            }
            if($(this).scrollTop() < (hdr*.85) && windowPosY ){
                mn.removeClass(mns);
                 $( ".iconcontainer li a" ).html( "<i class='fa fa-chevron-up hideicon'></i><br>Richard<br>Yee<br><i class='fa fa-chevron-down'>" );
                 $( ".iconcontainer li a" ).css( "font-size", "10px" );

            }
                if($(this).scrollTop() > (hdr+(gdr)) && windowPosY < (hdr+gdr+pdr)){
                    $( ".iconcontainer li a" ).html( "<i class='fa fa-chevron-up'></i><br>Painting?<br><i class='fa fa-chevron-down'>" );
                    $( ".iconcontainer li a" ).css( "font-size", "10px" );

                }
                if($(this).scrollTop() > (hdr+gdr+pdr) && windowPosY < (hdr+(gdr)+pdr+sdr)){
                    $( ".iconcontainer li a" ).html( "<i class='fa fa-chevron-up'></i><br>Sound<br><i class='fa fa-chevron-down hideicon'>" );
                    $( ".iconcontainer li a" ).css( "font-size", "10px" );
                }


            });

}
```

Is there a way to delay/get the variable of the heights after all the images in the div loads? I've tried alot of methods I've seen on Stack but I guess I haven't been able to implement them correctly. I'm not sure if my other messy JS is affecting it either, using Masonry to get the gridded images. Here's the rest of the code: https://github.com/yeemachine/yeemachine/blob/gh-pages/index.html

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are likely victim to a race condition. I.e., sometimes masonry js finishes sizing things before your code runs, and other times it does not.

***Do not solve this by adding a delay unless absolutely necessary.*** Adding a delay doesn't solve the problem: it just makes it less likely to happen. Instead, run your code after masonry tells you it has finished.

It looks like masonry js has some [events that you can hook into](http://masonry.desandro.com/events.html).

I'd see if running your code in the `layoutComplete` event solves your problem. E.g., something like:

```
// jQuery
var $grid = $('.grid').masonry({...});

function onLayout() {
  /* YOUR CODE HERE */
}
// bind event listener
$grid.on( 'layoutComplete', onLayout );
```

Comment: So I'm having a bit of trouble on linking the two together. Turns out the script managing the image grid is housed in the main.js file which ended up being an amalgamation of masonry, imageloaded, and modernizr, and I think the link between the two is GridFx, but I'm not sure. I'm lost on how to connect the two. https://github.com/yeemachine/yeemachine/blob/gh-pages/js/main.js

Comment: You could trigger an event in main.js when Masonry is ready, and listen for that event in your other script. Something like `var masonry = new Masonry(self.gridEl, { ... });` followed by `masonry.on( 'layoutComplete', function() { $('body').trigger('gridfx-loaded', [self]); });`. Unfortunately, this isn't the place to discuss restructuring your code, as it's unrelated to the original question. Open a new question if you have another.

Answer (score 1):

you may be attempting to read a dom element before its available causing a race condition of sometimes working and sometimes not.

You could simple delay and recall the same method to defer execution until the dom element is present.

```
var $pdr = $('.class2');
if ($pdr.length == 0)
    return window.setTimeout(arguments.callee, 10);

var pdr = $pdr.height();
```